# Open source React timeline UI component, similar to those used in video editing or multi-track audio editing?

Tags: web-development, video-editing, charts, user-interface, react

I'm looking for an open source React component that would let users drag and resize blocks horizontally over a timeline within different "swimlanes", similar to what you might see in a video editor (example in image below).

I've found https://github.com/xzdarcy/react-timeline-editor, which looks quite good, but I'm interested in comparing alternatives.

I suspect a good Gantt chart component could do the job, so feel free to include recommendations for those too! :)

[image]

Comment: I have a same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up just using https://github.com/xzdarcy/react-timeline-editor . It has turned out fine for my purpose.